# React Context Provider error with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, vite

I'm trying to create an auth/session context for my application. However, I am facing some errors when I attempt to build the Provider component and pass the children as props.

```
const AuthContext = createContext({})

type Props = {
    children: ReactNode
}

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: Props) => {
    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider>{children}</AuthContext>
    )
}
```

The following errors are appearing:

[Cannot find namespace 'AuthContext'.ts(2503)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6XpV.png)

[Unterminated regular expression literal.ts(1161)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPGQP.png)

I tried to write the code with more information to see if it was a type error, but it didn't solve the problem. When I try to take the same code and change the extension from TSX to JS the errors disappear.

Comment: The unterminated expression error occured because you closed your tag with `AuthContext` and not `AuthContext.Provider`. For the main problem, can you provide a working sandbox containing the error ?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code in my VScode and it works, it just points out that you need to close `<Authcontext.Provider>` with `</AuthContent.provider>` and that it need `value` as a parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first issue that you are facing:- Cannot find namespace 'AuthContext'.ts

Change your `.ts` file to `.tsx`
And in your `tsconfig.json` file make sure that `jsx` option is set to `react-jsx` under `compiler options` as below:-

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
...
}
```

For your second issue:- unterminated expression

Just close your `<AuthContext.Provider>` with `</AuthContext.Provider>`as below:-

```
const AuthContext = createContext({})

type Props = {
    children: ReactNode
}

export const AuthProvider = ({children}: Props) => {
    return(
        <AuthContext.Provider>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your file extension from `.ts` to `.tsx`